# Validate email address copied from Outlook

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Want to validate email fields where user can enter any kinds of emails .
My validation check using regex fails when user copy pasted email address from Outlook. Email address copied from Outlook looks different as

```
M, Karan <karan.m@outlook.com>
```

And my input looks like `m.karan@yahoo.com,M, Karan <karan.m@outlook.com>`. How to validate this input.

++adding code snippet

Am passing individual emails by splitting it with comma separator to below function,

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;    
  return re.test(email);
}
```

This logic broke when emails copied from outlook available in input element.

Looking forward for help.

Comment: This question is too vague. Please provide examples of your code or code you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just added code snippet that am using. As am adding it from Mobile, I don't see formatting options for code snippets. Apologies.

Comment: I suggest you break down the string. You may need to perform multiple passes. First, we know that there are certain characters that cannot be contained in an email address. Spaces being the first obvious character. I would split the string on the spaces, test each one to see if it's an email.

Comment: But if the input string is...m.karan@yahoo.com,M,Karan<m.karan@outlook.com. If I split using spaces.. It will fail validation check

Comment: That would require some operator error  since Outlook would put at least one space. Even if it didn't, the comma cannot be a part of the email, so split off that.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Solution**
Use regular expression like this (but concrete this regex is not the best of the world :) ):

```
^(([a-zA-Z\-0-9,.: ])*<){0,1}(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))>{0,1}$
```

**2. Solution**
Write JavaScript function that parse email and then use your regular expression. Here is example of parse function:

```
function parseEmail(origin) {
    return origin.substring(origin.lastIndexOf('<')+1, origin.lastIndexOf('>'));
}
```